# Python: Need to skip comments while opening a .ppm file

Tags: python, header, comments, grayscale, ppm

My program asks the user to enter a file name of a P6 .ppm image, then my program writes a new file as a P5 .pgm image converting it into Grayscale.
My program works perfectly except for if the image that is being opened has comments in the header. I'm not sure if my issue is in my Main() or my GetNum fucntion. Any help is much appreciated!

The start of my main looks like this

```
fileInput = raw_input("Enter the name of the original file including .ppm at the end: ")#P6 = .ppm
fileOutput = raw_input("Enter the file name for the new picture including .pgm at the end: ")#P5 = .pgm
readFile = open(fileInput, "rb")
writeFile = open(fileOutput, 'wb')
magicNumber1 = readFile.read(1)#MagicNumber 1 and 2 grabs the first two bytes for the header, which should be P6
magicNumber2 = readFile.read(1)
```

or does my problem exist in my GetNum function?

def GetNum(f):

```
currentChar = f.read(1) #Reads through the file 1 byte at a time

while currentChar.isdigit() == False:
    while currentChar.isspace(): #Keep reading if the current character is a space
        currentChar = f.read(1)

    if currentChar == "#": #If a comment or new line keep reading
        while currentChar != "\n":
            currentChar = f.read(1)

num = currentChar
while currentChar.isdigit(): #If current character is a digit, add it onto Num
    currentChar = f.read(1)
    num = num + currentChar

num = num.strip()

return num
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `GetNum(f)`.

At the end of this loop

```
while currentChar != "\n":
    currentChar = f.read(1)
```

`currentChar` is equal to `\n`

which means `num = currentChar`  sets `num` to `\n`

And because `currentChar` contains `\n` the next loop `while currentChar.isdigit()` never gets entered. So `num` doesn't get any digits added to it, and `num = num.strip()` strips out the `\n` it contains, so `GetNum(f)` returns an empty string.

...

Is there any reason you are parsing the PPM file yourself, rather than using a library? I'm assuming that this is a programming exercise, given that ppmtopgm exists.

FWIW, I often use NetPBM files, and in C I use my own parser, but in Python I generally use libraries for reading them; sometimes I use libraries for writing them, but the file format's so simple I often do it "by hand".

A nice way to approach parsing problems is to use a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

I should also mention that the Python module shlex can be used to do things like this, but I guess if this is a programming exercise you probably shouldn't use shlex. :)